# eval condition in javascript where the parameter type mismatch

Tags: javascript

I have script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   a = eval("dog!='cat'");
   document.write(a);
</script>
```

It give's "dog is not defined".But i want true/false.
If i put,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       a = eval("'dog'!='cat'");
       document.write(a);
    </script>
```

It works.
But i cannot put quotes to dog because condition dynamically generated, can any one suggest any other way to do it.
Here cat have quotes,but dog don't have the quotes.

Comment: Well.. are you defining `dog` and `cat`? If so, can you show the code where you define it? P.s you do realise [`eval()` is widely regarded as most evil feature of JavaScript, right?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval!)

Comment: No i didn't define any where.It is from textbox on my page.I am creating form dynamically.

Comment: `eval()` is evil lol! BTW @sandipkaranjekar do you know the difference between `dog` and `'dog'` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your operation to

- return `false` if `dog` is undefined
- return the result of comparison of `dog` and `'cat'` otherwise

just write

```
((typeof dog != 'undefined') && (dog != 'cat'))
```

You absolutely don't need the `eval` call. The above expression returns a boolean value, so you'll just have

```
a = ((typeof dog != 'undefined') && (dog != 'cat'))
document.write(a);
```

Also, I don't exactly understand, how is your "condition dynamically generated", but anyhow you do it, you can do it in a way such that `dog` is a variable (probably a string one), so you can use this code.

Comment: Suppose i have to on text box from that dog value is coming and 'cat' is condition for that text box then i want evaluate that condition with current value.I cannot remove eval function because it is used for other conditions also.

Comment: @sandipkaranjekar Yes, you can. Instead `eval("some_code");` you can just write `some_code`. Instead of `x = eval("some_expression")` you can write `x = some_expression`. With `eval`, you are launching a new instance of JS interpreter inside the one that interprets your usual code. Your programmer's intuition should hint you that this should not be necessary, at least not in such simple cases as form validation.

Answer (score 0):

If the value you are trying to compare is from a textbox on your page, you're going to have to get the value of that textbox and store it first.

Take for instance:

```
<input type="text" id="dogText" />
```

And you want to compare the text entered in that textbox with `'cat'`
First you'll need to get the value. Try jQuery.

```
var dog = $("#dogText").val();
a = (dog !== cat);
```

Make sure you use `!=` or `!==` depending on what you are actually looking for.

**OR** maybe you trying to do something like this?

You've said that your 'condition is dynamically generated'? Do you mean the string is dynamically generated? If this is the case then it means that you are getting `dog` from somewhere..

```
var str = 'dog'
var condition = "'" + str + "'!='cat'";
```

This adds quotes in, where they seem to be missing?

Then again I could be **WAY** off the mark again..